# Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input, searching online for one that does

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, blazor, project

Why do I get this error when creating a new project?

```
dotnet new blazor -o WebApplication1
```

[Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input searching online for one that does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ28b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this template does not exist. Try:

```
dotnet new blazorserver -o WebApplication1
```

or

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -o WebApplication1
```

[Check the differences here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0)